# Localization on ngx-smart-table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular, I have a table that I need to display with two languages based on the user's choice, I have searched a lot for this however, couldn't find anything useful for my case, I have made a work around that doesn't really fulfill my needs as when I go to another page and then back to this page it displays the data with the wrong choice as the variable inside the localstorage returns with undefined. Please advise if you have a better approach as I totally understand that mine is really bad. Thanks in advance.

employee.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.switchLanguage = localStorage.getItem('selectedLanguage');
this.lang = localStorage.getItem('lang')

this.getActiveEmployees();
}

getAllEmployees(){
if(this.switchLanguage === "en" || this.browserLang === "en"){
  console.log(this.switchLanguage + " Da5al hena lee 1")
  this.settings = {
    totalKey: 'total',
    pager: {
      display: true,
      perPage: '5'
    },
    mode: 'external',
    actions: false,
    columns: {
      firstName_FL: {
        title: 'First Name',
        data: this.employees.firstName_FL,
      },
      secondName_FL: {
        title: 'Second Name',
        data: this.employees.secondName_FL,
      },
      lastName_FL: {
        title: 'Last Name',
        data: this.employees.lastName_FL,
      },
      hiringDate: {
        title: 'Hiring Date',
        data: this.employees.hiringDate,
        type: 'date',
        filter: {
          type: 'daterange'
        },
        valuePrepareFunction: (lastLoginTime: any) => {
          return lastLoginTime.slice(0, 10)
        }
      },
      firstContractingSalary: {
        title: 'First Contracting Salary',
        valuePrepareFunction: (firstContractingSalary) => {
          this.formatedOutputValue = this.currenctPipe.transform(firstContractingSalary, 'EGP ', 
        'symbol', '1.2-2');
          return this.formatedOutputValue
        }
      },
      position: {
        title: 'Position',
        valuePrepareFunction: (position) => {
          return position.name_FL;
        },
        sort: true
      },
      department: {
        title: 'Department',
        valuePrepareFunction: (department) => {
          return department.name_FL;
        }
      },
      employeeJobStatuses: {
        title: 'Status',
        filter: false,
        sort: false,
        valuePrepareFunction: (employeeJobStatuses) => {
          this.statusValidation = employeeJobStatuses.map((element, i) => [
            element.status
          ])
          for(var i = 0; i < this.statusValidation.length; i++){
            if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_ACTIVE"){
              return "Active"
            } else if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_SUSPENDED"){
              return "Suspended"
            } else if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_TERMINATED"){
              return "Terminated"
            } else if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_INACTIVE"){
              return "Inactive"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  } else if(this.switchLanguage === "ar" || this.browserLang === "ar"){
  this.settings = {
    totalKey: 'total',
    pager: {
      display: true,
      perPage: '5'
    },
    mode: 'external',
    actions: false,
    columns: {
      firstName_SL: {
        title: 'الاسم الاول',
        data: this.employees.firstName_SL,
      },
      secondName_SL: {
        title: 'الاسم الاوسط',
        data: this.employees.secondName_SL,
      },
      lastName_SL: {
        title: 'الاسم الاخير',
        data: this.employees.lastName_SL,
      },
      hiringDate: {
        title: 'تاريخ التوظيف',
        data: this.employees.hiringDate,
        type: 'date',
        filter: {
          type: 'daterange'
        },
        valuePrepareFunction: (lastLoginTime: any) => {
          return lastLoginTime.slice(0, 10)
        }
      },
      firstContractingSalary: {
        title: 'قيمة التعاقد المبدأية',
        valuePrepareFunction: (firstContractingSalary) => {
          this.formatedOutputValue = this.currenctPipe.transform(firstContractingSalary, 'EGP ', 'symbol', '1.2-2');
          return this.formatedOutputValue
        }
      },
      position: {
        title: 'المركز',
        valuePrepareFunction: (position) => {
          return position.name_SL;
        },
        sort: true
      },
      department: {
        title: 'القسم',
        valuePrepareFunction: (department) => {
          return department.name_SL;
        }
      },
      employeeJobStatuses: {
        title: 'الحالة',
        filter: false,
        sort: false,
        valuePrepareFunction: (employeeJobStatuses) => {
          this.statusValidation = employeeJobStatuses.map((element, i) => [
            element.status
          ])
          for(var i = 0; i < this.statusValidation.length; i++){
            if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_ACTIVE"){
              return "نشيط"
            } else if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_SUSPENDED"){
              return "معلق"
            } else if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_TERMINATED"){
              return "منتهي"
            } else if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_INACTIVE"){
              return "غير نشط"
            }
          }   
        }

      }
    }
  };
}
 this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(language => {
    this.browserLang = language.lang;
    if(this.browserLang === "en"){
      this.settings = {
        totalKey: 'total',
        pager: {
          display: true,
          perPage: '5'
        },
        mode: 'external',
        actions: false,
        columns: {
          firstName_FL: {
            title: 'First Name',
            data: this.employees.firstName_FL,
          },
          secondName_FL: {
            title: 'Second Name',
            data: this.employees.secondName_FL,
          },
          lastName_FL: {
            title: 'Last Name',
            data: this.employees.lastName_FL,
          },
          hiringDate: {
            title: 'Hiring Date',
            data: this.employees.hiringDate,
            type: 'date',
            filter: {
              type: 'daterange'
            },
            valuePrepareFunction: (lastLoginTime: any) => {
              return lastLoginTime.slice(0, 10)
            }
          },
          firstContractingSalary: {
            title: 'First Contracting Salary',
            valuePrepareFunction: (firstContractingSalary) => {
              this.formatedOutputValue = this.currenctPipe.transform(firstContractingSalary, 'EGP ', 'symbol', '1.2-2');
              return this.formatedOutputValue
            }
          },
          position: {
            title: 'Position',
            valuePrepareFunction: (position) => {
              return position.name_FL;
            },
            sort: true
          },
          department: {
            title: 'Department',
            valuePrepareFunction: (department) => {
              return department.name_FL;
            }
          },
          employeeJobStatuses: {
            title: 'Status',
            filter: false,
            sort: false,
            valuePrepareFunction: (employeeJobStatuses) => {
              this.statusValidation = employeeJobStatuses.map((element, i) => [
                element.status
              ])
              for(var i = 0; i < this.statusValidation.length; i++){
                if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_ACTIVE"){
                  return "Active"
                } else if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_SUSPENDED"){
                  return "Suspended"
                } else if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_TERMINATED"){
                  return "Terminated"
                } else if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_INACTIVE"){
                  return "Inactive"
                }
              }   
            }

          }
        }
      };
    } else if(this.browserLang === "ar"){
      this.settings = {
        totalKey: 'total',
        pager: {
          display: true,
          perPage: '5'
        },
        mode: 'external',
        actions: false,
        columns: {
          firstName_SL: {
            title: 'الاسم الاول',
            data: this.employees.firstName_SL,
          },
          secondName_FL: {
            title: 'الاسم الاوسط',
            data: this.employees.secondName_SL,
          },
          lastName_FL: {
            title: 'الاسم الاخير',
            data: this.employees.lastName_SL,
          },
          hiringDate: {
            title: 'تاريخ التوظيف',
            data: this.employees.hiringDate,
            type: 'date',
            filter: {
              type: 'daterange'
            },
            valuePrepareFunction: (lastLoginTime: any) => {
              return lastLoginTime.slice(0, 10)
            }
          },
          firstContractingSalary: {
            title: 'قيمة التعاقد المبدأية',
            valuePrepareFunction: (firstContractingSalary) => {
              this.formatedOutputValue = this.currenctPipe.transform(firstContractingSalary, 'EGP ', 'symbol', '1.2-2');
              return this.formatedOutputValue
            }
          },
          position: {
            title: 'المركز',
            valuePrepareFunction: (position) => {
              return position.name_SL;
            },
            sort: true
          },
          department: {
            title: 'القسم',
            valuePrepareFunction: (department) => {
              return department.name_SL;
            }
          },
          employeeJobStatuses: {
            title: 'الحالة',
            filter: false,
            sort: false,
            valuePrepareFunction: (employeeJobStatuses) => {
              this.statusValidation = employeeJobStatuses.map((element, i) => [
                element.status
              ])
              for(var i = 0; i < this.statusValidation.length; i++){
                if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_ACTIVE"){
                  return "نشيط"
                } else if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_SUSPENDED"){
                  return "معلق"
                } else if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_TERMINATED"){
                  return "منتهي"
                } else if(this.statusValidation[i][i] === "STATUS_INACTIVE"){
                  return "غير نشط"
                }
              }   
            }

          }
        }
      };
    }
  })
this.loading = true;
this.restService.GetAllEmployees().subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.loading = false;
  this.employees = res.data.employees;
  const maw = JSON.stringify(this.employees)
  this.jsonObj = JSON.parse(maw);
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dont forget to inject TranslateService in ur constrctor ,and add id , name resources in ar.josn , and en.json ,try this

```
  columnheaders:any;
    ngOnInit(){
    this.columnheaders = []
    this.translate.get('the id').subscribe(label =>this.columnheaders[0]= label);
    this.translate.get('the name').subscribe(label =>this.columnheaders[1]= label);
    }


  this.settings = {
    columns: {
    name: {
          title:this.columnheaders[0],
          type: 'string',
        }
        name: {
          title:this.columnheaders[1],
          type: 'string',
        }
}}
```